# Upgrading React native from 0.57 to 0.58.5

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After upgrading to `React Native` 0.58.5 from 0.57, there is an error whenever installing a `npm` module:

```
npm WARN react-native@0.58.5 requires a peer of react@16.6.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm ERR! path C:\d\code\js\emps\node_modules\colors
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\d\code\js\emps\node_modules\colors' -> 'C:\d\code\js\emps\node_modules\.colors.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JunC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-25T23_49_59_940Z-debug.log
```

Here is the part of `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-native": "^0.58.5",
    "react-native-code-push": "^5.5.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.26.4",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.7.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.0"
  },
```

The `react` version is alreay `16.8.2` which is newer than what the message suggests. What causes the error message? Is the `react-native` too new?

Comment: Have you tried `npm ci` to start with a clean installation?

Comment: Probably not. I can't remember I did that. The project was created with react native 0.57 a few weeks before and I did upgrade it to 0.58.5 and this is when I start seeing the error. Is there a way to fix the error?

Comment: I mean that you could try writing `npm ci` right now to remove all `node_modules` and start with a fresh install.

Comment: did you directly changed version in package.json and then did npm install ?

Comment: What I did was to reinstall the whole system and notice that the react version is locked at 16.6.2 which is not the latest one (16.8.2).  The problem may be incompatibility issues caused by newer `react`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up reinstalling the whole system and notice that the react version is locked at 16.6.2 which is not the latest one (16.8.2). The problem may be incompatibility issues caused by newer react. Here is part of `package.json` after re-installation:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.5",
    "react-native-code-push": "^5.5.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.26.4",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.12.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.52.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Comment: That would seem right given that on the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0578) the last mention of a `react` version bump was in `0.57.8` also looking at the [git diff](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.57.0...version/0.58.5#diff-ed1b36cdbc3145ad164d87d0b7185565R10) between `0.57` and `0.58.5` there was a bump from `16.5.0` to `16.6.3`

Answer (score 1):

pertaining to the `npm ERR!`, you are required to run `npm install color -S` as the `color` package is missing from your json file.

hope this helps!